# Meteor : Email a Template in Client using Mailgun

Tags: email, templates, meteor, server, mailgun

I have a Template in client

```
<template name="sendThis">
<img src="logo.png"><br>
<h3>Welcome to Meteor NewBie</h3>
Dear {{name}},
<p>You received this Email because you have subscribed to http://www.example.com</p>
</template>
```

I would like to send this Template(sendThis) as HTML body in my Email to subscribers.

I am using Mailgun as my Email Client. What are the steps I should take to make this happen as a subscriber clicks a button with an id "subscribe".

PS: I have multiple helpers in this template, multiple in the sense more than 20.

Thanks in advance.
Mahesh B.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use [Blaze.toHTMLWithData](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_tohtmlwithdata) to render your template (with a context) to an HTML string. You can then call a method on your server which emails the user with the appropriate subject and address. Here's an example:

### client

```js
var sendSignupEmail = function() {
  // This assumes this first email address is the one you want.
  // In some cases you may want the first verified email, but not
  // during signup.
  var address = Meteor.user().emails[0].address;

  var subject = 'Thanks for signing up!';

  // Here I used username - replace this with the appropriate data
  // like Meteor.user().profile.firstName or something.
  var body = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.sendThis, {
    name: Meteor.user().username
  });
  Meteor.call('sendEmail', address, subject, body);
};
```

### server

```js
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function(to, subject, html) {
    check([to, subject, html], [String]);
    this.unblock();

    return Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: 'something@example.com',
      subject: subject,
      html: html
    });
  }
});
```

Also make sure your [MAIL_URL](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email) environment variable has been defined.

Comment: How can we bring some helpers to this

`var body = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.sendThis, {
    name: Meteor.user().username
  });`

as we have names here, can we call some functions inside this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Can you be more specific? If you do a simple test with the above code does it work for you?

Comment: I have `name` as a variable here. Which is Meteor.user().username .
and I would like to add some more variable to this template, some of them are calculated values from other templates or Mongo DB.

My Question is, as we added `name` to the Emailing Template, can we add other required data from database to this template? I guess that call should happen inside the Blaze.toHTMLWithDate()

Hope you got my Idea, else I can share you some more code I have

Comment: It's a template like any other - you are just rendering it to a string instead of into the body of the page. This means you can pass whatever context you like, use helpers, etc. As an example, you can create a new project, click the button in the `hello` template, and then call `Blaze.toHTML(Template.hello)` and you'll see a string containing `'<p>You've pressed the button 1 times.</p>'`.